# Integrate $\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^7(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^7(x)}\,dx$

I tried $\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^5(x)}\,dx$

thean by replacing $\tan^2(x)=t\:\:$ I have $\:\:dx=2\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)}$ but can't get so far with trig manipulations.

Need a bit help if possible :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**hint**

Write it as
$$\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^8(x)}\cos(x)dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{(1-\sin^2(x))^4}d(\sin(x))$$

$$=\int \frac{ t^2dt}{(1-t^2)^4}$$

$$=- \int (\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^3}-\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^4})dt$$

By parts,

$$\int \frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^n}=$$

$$\Bigl[\frac{t}{(1-t^2)^n}\Bigr]+2n\int \frac{1-t^2+1}{(1-t^2)^{n+1}}dt$$

Comment: thank you so much @hamam :)

Comment: @John I think if you  expand in partial fractions, but it is too long.

Comment: To this $\int\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^3}dt\:\:$ i sub.$\:\:t=sin(t)$ after all i got $\int\frac{1}{cos^5(t)}dt$ is there any simplier way to solve it :)

Comment: @John No, you can use recursive relation i gave starting by $ \int dt/(1-t^2) =1/2\ln((1+t)(1-t))$.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite
$\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^7x}\,dx
= \int \sec^7x dx - \int \sec^5x dx 
$
and apply the recursive fomula

$$\int \sec^n x \ dx =I_n
=\frac{\tan x\sec^{n-2}x}{n-1}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}I_{n-2}
$$
to obtain
$$\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^7x}\,dx
= {\tan x}\left(\frac16\sec^5x -\frac1{24}\sec^3x-\frac1{16}\sec x \right)-\frac1{16}I_0
$$
with $I_0=\int \sec x\ dx = \tanh^{-1}\sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

The first idea that I thought of is rewriting the numerator as $1-\cos^2x$; this shows that the integral is equivalent to
$$\int\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^7x}dx=\int\sec^7x-\sec^5x~dx$$
Now, these integrals can be solved by using integration by parts, as follows.
$$\begin{align}\int\sec^7x~dx&=\int\sec^2x\cdot\sec^5x~dx=\sec^5x\tan x-\int 5\sec^5x\tan x\cdot\tan x~dx\\
&=\sec^5x\tan x-5\int\sec^5x\tan^2x~dx\\
&=\sec^5x\tan x-5\int\sec^5x(\sec^2x-1)~dx\\
&=\sec^5x\tan x-5\int\sec^7x~dx+5\int\sec^5x~dx\end{align}$$
and therefore
$$6\int\sec^7x~dx=\sec^5x\tan x+5\int\sec^5x~dx$$
and so on.

This is a pretty tedious method, and to be honest I much prefer hamam-Abdallah's answer.